# local user not visible in sqldeveloper in Oracle 12g database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, local

I have created a local user with name `njams` in a PGB, but why I cannot see this local user under "other users" in sqldeveloper although this user is listed when

```
Select * FROM ALL_USERS ORDER BY USERNAME;
```

is executed?

Comment: Are you connected to the pluggable DB where the user was created, or to the container? Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: Im using sqldeveloper version number 4.0.3.16  and I have connection to the PGB (only there the local user is listed)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Pluggable Database, PDB. In a pluggable, the 'other users' list is populated with 'SELECT * from (select username from sys.all_users where username != USER)' - where 'USER' is YOU.